# How to display only order total in paypal checkout page as like ebay do

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

have a weird problem.As I have a shopping cart on my website I decided to integrate this to paypal. Its working like charm

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@test.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.50">
<input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

What happens was I decided to **not to show item wise descriptions except order total** in paypal cehckout page(just like ebay do).

[image: ebay]

So i change my code as follows

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@test.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.40">
    <input type="submit" value="PayPal">
    </form>
```

But when i use this,on the checkout page it appears like this
[image: paypal checkout]

Please help what I have done wrong? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know how they do that but i know that, Owner of paypal is eBay Inc.

You can display your company logo by just putting one more hidden field

value="http://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/e/e2/Fedora-infinity-logo-64-64.png">

Comment: Thanks friend,I also knew that.